# SAP incremental data load in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, sap-erp, incremental-load

I'm trying to implement an Extractor pipeline in ADF, with several Copy Data activities (SAP ERP Table sources). To save some processing time, I'd like to have some deltas (incremental load). What's the best way to implement this?

What I'm trying at the moment is just to use the "RFC table options" in each Copy Data activity. However, this seems to be quite limited (only very simple queries allowed). Also, each SAP ERP table requires a different query. I found 3 different situations, regarding table field formats:

- Timestamp in miliseconds (e.g. COVP);
- Timestamp in YYYYMMDDHHMMSS (e.g. FAGLFLEXA);
- Last change date and last change time, in separated fields (e.g. CATSDB)

Has anyone ever tried this? What would you advise?

Thanks!